# add a Menu to my WordPress Theme footer.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom footer to my WordPress theme, I upload my static website [here](http://royayeketab.ir/) and now I trying to make it dynamic, I added my primary menu to WordPress but I don't know how can I exactly add footer to my wordpress theme?

do I have to make another menu and use it here like

```
$args= array(
    'theme_location' => 'footer'
    );
wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

and then register it in function.php
or it has another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You may want to display it by registering dynamic widget and displaying in your `footer.php` instead:

**Registering Footer Widget**

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'footer Sidebar 1',
    'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1',
    'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class=" %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
) );
```

**displaying Footer widget**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <?php
        if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
            dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Then in your `Dashboard Widget Menu` add your custom code via **Text Widget** placing into your `footer-sidebar-1` sidebar.

Hope it works..

Comment: yes but my footer contain 3 column so should I have 3 menu for this part? and also I have logo and my social networks links and I don't know how I put theme in menu?

Comment: why don't you register widget for this ? I recommend registering 3 widgets and doing some css tricks for display. 

If you want it as 3 column menus, I guess you need to register 3 nav_menus.  But I think the standard way is registering footer widgets.

Comment: aha and do you recommend special plugin for something like this?

Comment: hmm, I think it's better to register custom footer_sidebar https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

and display in footer.php as:

     `<div class="col-sm-4">
      <?php
      if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
       dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
      }
      ?>`

something like this.

Comment: let me test it. now I try to create widget for this? then if it doesn't work I make sidebar for this part. thank you :D

Comment: sure, ping me if you got any problem in this.. xD but first try it yourself.. ;)

Comment: I did it and work fine but I have some problem with third-column I want to add to widget search box , I create widget menu for first 2 column but for third one I don't know how can I make it @Prabin Parajuli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121133/discussion-between-prabin-parajuli-and-mimi).